# iconv Missing Encodings

Tags: locale, encoding

For some reason, my iconv is missing the "latin1" encoding type which I need in R. Indeed, using the `iconv -l` command, I find that the latin1 encoding type is missing as  shown below

========================================

(First Machine)

```
  10646-1:1993, 10646-1:1993/UCS4, ANSI_X3.4-1968, ANSI_X3.4-1986, ANSI_X3.4,
  ASCII, CP367, CSASCII, CSUCS4, IBM367, ISO-10646, ISO-10646/UCS2,
  ISO-10646/UCS4, ISO-10646/UTF-8, ISO-10646/UTF8, ISO-IR-6, ISO-IR-193,
  ISO646-US, ISO_646.IRV:1991, OSF00010020, OSF00010100, OSF00010101,
  OSF00010102, OSF00010104, OSF00010105, OSF00010106, OSF05010001, UCS-2,
  UCS-2BE, UCS-2LE, UCS-4, UCS-4BE, UCS-4LE, UCS2, UCS4, UNICODEBIG,
  UNICODELITTLE, US-ASCII, US, UTF-8, UTF8, WCHAR_T
```

=========================================

(Second Machine)

```
$ iconv -l | grep LATIN

CSISO19LATINGREEK//
CSISO27LATINGREEK1//
CSISOLATIN1//
CSISOLATIN2//
CSISOLATIN3//
CSISOLATIN4//
CSISOLATIN5//
CSISOLATIN6//
CSISOLATINARABIC//
CSISOLATINCYRILLIC//
CSISOLATINGREEK//
CSISOLATINHEBREW//
CSPC862LATINHEBREW//
LATIN-9//
LATIN-GREEK-1//
LATIN-GREEK//
LATIN1//
LATIN2//
LATIN3//
LATIN4//
LATIN5//
LATIN6//
LATIN7//
LATIN8//
LATIN9//
LATIN10//
LATINGREEK//
LATINGREEK1//
OS2LATIN1//
```

=========================================

The latin1 encoding type is however available on a second machine with the same  operating system. (I've used the exact same copy of the `iconv` program for both machines so it is not a `iconv` problem) Could someone advise me on how I can get the "latin1" encoding type installed for usage in `iconv` in the first system?

=========================================

Update #1

The test results for machine 2 above was done on my own account. If I used the root account, I could get the latin1 font. The latin1 font is however also not available using other non-root accounts. So I guess there is no issue with the system but there is an issue with how each of the user accounts are configured?

Comment: Your question is not about fonts but about encodings. You may want to make sure that the `libc6` package is correctly installed.

Comment: The first machine is almost certainly not Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

use the iconv provided by GLIBC
eg:

```
$ iconv --version
iconv (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.31-0ubuntu9.2) 2.31
Copyright © 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
Ce logiciel est libre; voir les sources pour les conditions de
reproduction. AUCUNE garantie n'est donnée; tant pour des raisons
COMMERCIALES que pour RÉPONDRE À UN BESOIN PARTICULIER.
Écrit par Ulrich Drepper.
```

If you use iconv as C/C++ library you must not precise the iconv library, eg:

```
$ gcc -o exec code.c -liconv   #NOOOOOOOO
```

Unstead do this:

code.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iconv.h>
 
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    (...)
    iconv_t conv = iconv_open("UTF-8","IBM500");
    iconv(conv, &pIn, &srclen, &pOut, &dstlen);
    iconv_close(conv);
    (...)
}
```

Compile the code using the standard glibc:

```
$ gcc -o exec code.c
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party but it looks like `iconv` isn't able to find the converter plugins which is probably due to not finding `gconv-modules` and `gconv-modules.cache`.

The plugins are typically located in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gconv/` on an AMD64-machine or something like `/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/gconv/` on an ARM-machine. This is also where you'd find `gconv-modules` and `gconv-modules.cache`.

Running `strace iconv -l` should tell you if it fails to open the `gconv-modules` and `gconv-modules.cache` files and where it looks for them. After that you can create symlinks to the actual files.

After reading Update #1 my guess is that the `GCONV_PATH` env variable is properly set for the root-account but not for your account. Setting `GCONV_PATH` should be an alternative to creating symlinks (I haven't tried it). The advantage with symlinks in this case is that it works for all users out of the box (if you create the symlinks correctly).